# Powershell script to remove members from AD groups not working on all groups/users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following code that removes the membership of users in a specific OU that is not working on some users. I tested the lines from $UserDN to the removal and it worked as expected in one user, fixing the DN.

Would you help me find out why this would happen?

Thank you!

```
    {
        $CurrentAction = $Message
        $TraceLog += ((Get-Date).ToString() + "`t" + $Message + " `r`n") | add-content  ‘D:\Logs\AD Removal\logfile_’ + $datestring + ‘.log’
        
    }

$path = "OU=Tango,OU=People,DC=Lab,DC=Dev";

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $path -Properties memberof| Select DistinguishedName, @{n='memberOf';e={$_.memberOf -join '; '}} | export-csv d:/Remove AD Membership/usersbeforescript.csv -NoTypeInformation

$ExceptGroup = "Domain Users";
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter *

foreach ($user in $users) {
        try {
            $UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
            Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
                if ($_.name -ne $ExceptGroup) {
                    Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $_.name -Member $UserDN -confirm:$false
        }
            AppendLog “Removed group $_.name from $user”
                }
         catch {
                     AppendLog ”Failed to remove group $_.name from $user”
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: _"is not working on some users"_ why? are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi Santiago, no errors, it just seems to skip those users. even if they're in the target OU. I launched the .ps1, I will try to run it manually to see if any errors I might not see because it got closed after finishing. You gave me a good idea there. Thanks !

Comment: Also note, the code posted in question has a syntax error, there is a missing closing `}` in your `try` statement and there is an extra closing `}` after your `catch`

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I have it actually corrected but didn't notice I pasted the script with the wrong syntax.

Comment: In regards of the script, I had to run it again and removed the users from their membership apart from three users. One of the users has a few global groups and the script returns that it cannot find the group, even if they're in the same domain. The second and third users have groups that are nested to other security groups, might this prevent the removal using PS? They are not member of the parent groups.

Comment: BTW, the path `d:/Remove AD Membership/usersbeforescript.csv` has spaces in it, so that needs to be quoted

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what exactly caused an exception, you need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` on the cmdlet(s) inside a `try{..}` block, so when an error occurs you can get its details in the `catch{..}` block.

For that, I would write your `foreach ($user in $users) {..}` loop like this:

```
$path = "OU=Tango,OU=People,DC=Lab,DC=Dev"
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter * -Properties MemberOf

# export to csv before removing users from groups
$users | Select DistinguishedName, @{n='MemberOf';e={$_.MemberOf -join '; '}} -ExcludeProperty MemberOf | 
         Export-Csv -Path 'd:\Remove AD Membership/usersbeforescript.csv' -NoTypeInformation

$ExceptGroup = "Domain Users"


foreach ($user in $users) {
    $filter = "(member=$($user.DistinguishedName))"
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $filter | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $ExceptGroup } | ForEach-Object {
        # store the group name in a variable for when we hit the catch block
        $group = $_.Name
        try {
            # append -ErrorAction Stop to catch also non-terminating exceptions
            $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
            AppendLog "Removed user $($user.Name) from group $group"
        }
        catch {
            # inside the catch block, automatic variable $_ is the error object itself
            AppendLog "Failed to remove user $($user.Name) from group $group`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- we cannot see the code for your custom `AppendLog` function so I can only assume this does what it is supposed to do
- there is no need to do a `Get-ADUser` twice
- the output path for the CSV file should be quoted as it contains spaces
- it is best to not use curly typographic quotes like `”` in code as that might someday present you with weird errors..